# Does the nfolds chose for H2O cross validation change the percentage of data used?

Tags: python, cross-validation, h2o, k-fold

The H2O manual describes how the data is split for k-fold cross validation. The example given is for a 5 fold cross validation.

see here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/nfolds.html which states:

**"The first 5 models (cross-validation models) are built on 80% of the training data, and a different 20% is held out for each of the 5 models."**

If a different fold value was chosen, will these percentages be different for example, suppose 10 was chosen as the number of folds, would the following be true?

**'The first 10 models (cross-validation models) are built on 90% of the training data, and a different 10% is held out for each of the 10 models.'**

Comment: I can see this would be true after seeing it wrote down. I will leave it in case anyone wants to answer or add.

Comment: I think that basically you have to divide the number of rows in the training frame with the number of folds. If you choose a high value for k, there will be more data for the training, but at the same time you will require more computational effort since more models will be trained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  The percentage of the data used for training is determined by the number of folds.